# Enigmatic Animals

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, knowledge, animals

What are the three animals? The clues are separate from one another and get harder as they progress.

Animal 1:

> I live in the shadows
>   I don't let anyone else play in the bushes

Animal 2:

> Ripped because he was in a hurry but left his h at home

Animal 3:

> Long surf
>   Onety one
>   Baby sheep(Obviously you fool)
>   The answer's above you

Hint 1 (For Animal 3):

> The first 3 lines should be viewed separately from the fourth.

Hint 2 (For Animal 3):

> The Answer is waaaay above you

Hint 3: Big hint based on what has already been discussed in comments:

> Looks like lambda above you

Hint 4:

> I am only visible at certain times of the day

Hint 5:

> I Used to help sailors navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animal 1 (From jsm)

> Hedgehog

Animal 2 (From Chowzen)

> Taurus (Bull)

Animal 3 (From Hagfy)

> Bear

Another good guess would've been:

> Fish

Based On:

> Pisces is a constellation that has been used for navigation (as with most other common constellations); Pisces also contains the star [*λ Piscium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_Piscium) which is a bright white star located in the southeast corner of the circlet.

Comment: Your second guess was right

Answer (score 6):

1: Sounds like it's a

> Hedgehog

2: It's a bit of a stretch, but is it a

> Tortoise (tore + dash, without the h)

[edit]

> Tortoise (tore to his, without the h = tor to 'is)

3: I'm working on it!

Comment: Correct for the first and you've got half of the second

Answer (score 5):

For #1 (from @jsm):

> Hedgehog (nocturnal (live in shadows), and frequents hedgerows.)

For #2 (stretching?)

> Tore + Rus(h) =  Taurus (bull)

For #3 (*really* stretching!)

> <s>long + anagram(surf)→long furs + 11→LL + lam(b) + a? = Llama
>  A Llama has long fur.</s>

Told you it was a stretch.

**Revised** #3 (continuing to stretch)

> The first three lines signify "Lamda" per @GustavoGabriel
>  The answer (Lamb, duh) is [above you](https://www.google.com/search?q=lamb+nursing+under+ewe&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVyrC6r4DbAhWkpFkKHVBmDHsQ_AUICygC&biw=1093&bih=539) (Ewe) → The animal is a Ewe.

Comment: Nice lateral thinking, there.

Comment: To clarify you got 2 correct not 3 :)

Answer (score 5):

New partially-correct answer for #3:

> It's pretty certainly star-related, so probably a constellation?  Not sure of an old constellation that looks like 3 lambdas.
> These are almost-certainly wrong, but I'm stuck on Aries (RAM/LAMB-related) and Ursa Major (BEAR-related)
>
> Actually, my original answer was correct except the last line, so has it been **BEAR** this whole time, just the reasoning was incorrect?

The rest of my sordid thought process is below.

---

<strike>Answer for #3 (which is "correct for the first part but not the last line"):</strike>

> Bear

Long surf

> From @DanielBaliki - Long =  length, surf = wave: wavelength.  In physics, the symbol used for wavelength is Lambda

Onety one

> Onety-one is a 'different' way to write 11.  Eleventh letter of the Greek alphabet is Lambda

Baby sheep(Obviously you fool)

> Baby sheep = lamb, Obviously = duh: Lambda

The answer's above you

> These three together are the life-imitating-art fraternity of Lambda Lambda Lambda.  Above their crest is a bear.

---

Alternatively (per @noedne) -

> The letter above/before Lambda is Kappa, which could refer to this:
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_(folklore)

---

My final attempt at an answer, building in an entirely coherent and logical way from @noedne's comments -

> An oxpecker on the head of a giraffe on the shoulders of a second giraffe who is itself on top of another giraffe
> . <--oxpecker
> λ
> λ
> λ
> ~~~ <--hilly savanna

Honestly, I'm just stretching based on other comments at this point, so I don't plan to update this again unless I have some kind of animal-epiphany, as taking any credit for whatever the final answer is would be wrong.

---

So, based on this last hint, guessing it's just:

> !Three flying Vs (uppercase lambda) of 'birds'?

Comment: Very interesting answer. Your correct for the first part but not the last line

Comment: I'm interpreting long surf as another way of saying wavelength. In physics, the symbol for wavelength is lambda.

Comment: @DanielBaliki That makes perfect sense (to me).  Thanks!

Comment: (Stretching) Maybe [ROT13](http://www.rot13.com/)(n [xnccn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_(folklore)))?

Comment: @noedne I did consider that, but it seemed strange to have 3x 'Ynzoqn' with the 4th line only appearing once.  Since you mentioned it though, I'll add it as a potential answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @hagfy You're right, it doesn't even fit well at all. I have no faith in it, but I was hoping to give direction to interpreting the final clue.

Comment: @noedne Since my original answer was incorrect, I've been entirely adrift.  Your direction was much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps [ROT13](https://www.rot13.com/)(n tvenssr, juvpu [ybbxf yvxr n ynzoqn](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1536&bih=759&ei=HRX4WpPUCeSN_QbSupCoDw&q=giraffe+lambda&oq=giraffe+lambda&gs_l=img.3..35i39k1.1094.3197.0.3431.17.16.1.0.0.0.78.921.15.15.0....0...1.1.64.img..1.16.920.0..0j0i24k1.0.tw8YqGa1Xg4))?

Comment: noedne is going in the right direction

Comment: Is it just me or does (rot13)ynzoqn ybbxf yvxr ongf unatvat hcfvqr qbja?

Comment: @Cgz Not sure...seems like it could be valid.  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: is it possibly rot13 N sybpx bs trrfr?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for #3

The answer's above you

> Roof, sounds like a dog bark or wolf, maybe related?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for number 2:

> Hare. If you remove the h letter it become 'Are', as in plural (ripped apart).

Comment: #2 was [credited as solved](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65623/enigmatic-animals/65641#comment198512_65641) by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt based on hint #5:

> A seagull (or better, three of them)

Because

> They used to help sailors navigate by signalling when the lands was close.

---

Stretchy guess for the third animal:

> A bat

Because

> If you write three uppercase lambda, ΛΛΛ, it could kinda look like a very stylised bat.

Also:

> the first one about lambda as the symbol for wavelength could be a hint for bats' echolocation ability; the last line hints at a flying animal; the fourth hint may refer at the fact that you see bats only at night.

So we have

> #1: hedgehog, #2: Taurus and #3: bat.